# Earth Science Home Page Formatting

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) has an extraordinary Background Design when you enter it, maybe this explains why it has such an active user base and far more Members than Earth Science SE.

All of the Beta Sites don't have such a Background Design and special Formatting compared to other sites.

Is there any explanation for no Special Banner?

Comment: That can't be done in beta mode. We need to wait to be a full site https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290359/995796